# Advanced array/dataframe slicing (numpy/pandas)

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I'm trying to generate 50 random samples of 30 continuous day periods from a list of corn prices (which is index by date).

So far I've got 'select 50 random days' on line one. For the second line, what I really want is an array of dataframes, each one containing 30 days from sample date. Currently it just returns the price on that day.

```
samples=np.random.choice(corn[:'1981'].index,50)
corn['Open'][samples] #line I need to fix
```

What's the cleanest way of doing that?

Comment: what is `corn` before hand?

Comment: corn['Open'] is a pandas series of the form (date, price) where date is the index.

Comment: I haven't used pandas / numpy much but would `zip(samples, corn["Open"][samples])` be what you are looking for?

Comment: I couldn't understand based on your description. Can you give a sample table? How should it look like?

Comment: You could also use pandas' [`sample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) method to get random samples, I find it more elegant than the numpy method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use

```
corn.loc[date:date+pd.Timedelta(days=29)]
```

to select 30 days worth of rows starting from date `date`. Note that  `.loc[start:end]` includes both `start` and `end` (unlike Python slices, which use half-open intervals). Thus adding 29 days to `date` results in a DataFrame of length 30.

To get an list of DataFrames, use a list comprehension:

```
dfs = [corn.loc[date:date+pd.Timedelta(days=29)] for date in samples]
```

---

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

N = 365
corn = pd.DataFrame({'Open': np.random.random(N)}, 
                    index=pd.date_range('1980-1-1', periods=N))
samples = np.random.choice(corn[:'1981'].index,50)
dfs = [corn.loc[date:date+pd.Timedelta(days=29)] for date in samples]
```

Comment: Very clever, just what I was looking for. Thanks very much!